# Find in XML and read only that part

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an XML file with some login information that I need to search for login name, and find relevant data for the account.

The XML file I have looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--GroupTool2 bot settings file-->
<!--Please do not make any manual changes to this file!-->
<GroupTool2_Settings>
  <SavedBots>
    <BotName>Midday Ibor</BotName>
    <BotPass>Password Hash</BotPass>
    <BotMaster>Master Trapper</BotMaster>
    <BotGroup>MyGroup</BotGroup>
    <StartLocation>@Home/</StartLocation>
    <DontSend>1</DontSend>
    <DaysBetweenInvited>11</DaysBetweenInvited>
  </SavedBots>
  <SavedBots>
    ...
  </SavedBots>
</GroupTool2_Settings>
```

What I need to do, is to be able to search the document for the BotName, and only read the data between  that is relevant to the BotName I am searching for.

But there are moe troubles along the way.
The BotName are not always stored as "FirstName LastName", it could also be stored as "FirstName" and "FirstName.LastName"

The variables I will always have aailable to search for, however, is ALWAYS the string BotFName and BotLname. In the cases that the saved BotName is only FirstName, the LastName used will always be a certain name, so the LastName could simply just be dropped when it comes to search for the name in the document.

I am also not the author of the XML document in question, so it can not be changed to simplify my search.

I am however not looking for a full solution, just a short pseudo example so I know where to begin.
Any help is apreciated.

/Rickard

Answer (score 1):

You may search an element via Linq-XML.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 string search="Midday Ibor";
 var savedBots = doc.Descendants("SavedBots").Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value == search).FirstOrDefault();

 if (savedBots != null)
  {
   Console.WriteLine((string)savedBots.Element("BotPass"));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Now I just have to figure out how to make two versions of that var.
I would need to use either:

    var savedBots = doc.Descendants("SavedBots").Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value.Replace(' ', '.') == search).FirstOrDefault();

or

    var savedBots = doc.Descendants("SavedBots").Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value == search).FirstOrDefault();

Depending on how the name is saved in the XML file.

Comment: @Rickard - You have to use || (or) operator. `Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value == search || p.Element("BotName").Value.Replace(' ', '.') == search).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Ahh, thank you AVD.
I didn't know I could use the OR operator there.
Thank you :)